# Changing IF ELSE to CASE

Tags: mysql

I have the following block in my Stored procedure. It is working as expected.
But I want to change it to CASE so that I can add more conditions later as reqired.

```
IF parm_status='ALL' THEN 
    IF op_type='CREDIT' THEN
        set v_wherestr =concat( v_wherestr, " and (tran.operation='CREDIT')");
    ELSEIF op_type='UNCREDIT' THEN
    set v_wherestr = concat( v_wherestr, " and (tran.operation='CREDIT' OR tran.operation='UNCREDIT')");
    END IF;

...
...

END IF;
```

Comment: So why dont you? Whats stopping you? Whats the real problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it would be:

```
IF parm_status='ALL' THEN 
    CASE op_type
       WHEN 'CREDIT' THEN set v_wherestr =concat( v_wherestr, " and (tran.operation='CREDIT')");
       WHEN 'UNCREDIT' THEN set v_wherestr = concat( v_wherestr, " and (tran.operation='CREDIT' OR tran.operation='UNCREDIT')");
    END;

...
...

END IF;
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Flow-Control/UseCASEWHENforstringvalue.htm

This keeps your original structure but replaces the IF THEN statements with a CASE statement.  However, I would look at your actual query to see if maybe there is a more optimal way of accomplishing what you want to do.  Even though this is a stored procedure, the execution plan will be a mess most likely.  You might want to play around with multiple queries combined through UNION ALL or something else in order to make this more optimized.  I'm sorry I can't help you further here but it really depends on your overall query and your data structure.

Comment: Does case work as a block like that? - Thought it was just for inline sql.

Comment: If the IF statement works, I believe the CASE statement will work as well.  I was trying not to modify the statement any more than I had to because I wasn't sure what would make it better and what would make it worse.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true: IF is a T-SQL block, and Case is for in-line. If you look at the example link all those uses are inline - in otherwords they are part of a sql statement rather than for block flow control. Similarly I don't think IF will work in an inline select statement.

Comment: Looking here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html, IF is a contruct, whereas Case is an operator, to give them their proper labels.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
IF parm_status='ALL' THEN 
    set v_wherestr = 
        CASE op_type
           WHEN 'CREDIT' THEN concat( v_wherestr, " and (tran.operation='CREDIT')");
           WHEN 'UNCREDIT' THEN concat( v_wherestr, " and (tran.operation='CREDIT' OR tran.operation='UNCREDIT')");
        END;

... ...

END IF;
```

or even (this is less flexible):

```
IF parm_status='ALL' THEN 
    set v_wherestr = concat( v_wherestr, 
        CASE op_type
           WHEN 'CREDIT' THEN " and (tran.operation='CREDIT')"
           WHEN 'UNCREDIT' THEN " and (tran.operation='CREDIT' OR tran.operation='UNCREDIT')"
        END;
    );
... ...

END IF;
```